# OCaml Option get

Tags: ocaml, option-type

I'm new to OCaml, I'm trying to understand how you're supposed to get the value from an 'a option.  According to the doc at http://ocaml-lib.sourceforge.net/doc/Option.html, there is a get function of type 'a option -> 'a that does what I want.  but when I type:

```
# let z = Some 3;;
val z : int option = Some 3
# get z;;
Error: Unbound value get
# Option.get z;;
Error: Unbound module Option
```

Why isnt this working?

Comment: You are looking at the documentation for ocaml-lib, an optional utility library for OCaml. Of course you do not need that library to access the value inside a `Some` constructor.

Comment: @ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine don't just remove the [tag:option] tag. The meta post it refers to says questions should be retagged, in this case with [tag:option-type].

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The traditional way to obtain the value inside any kind of constructor in OCaml is with pattern-matching. Pattern-matching is the part of OCaml that may be most different from what you have already seen in other languages, so I would recommend that you do not just write programs the way you are used to (for instance circumventing the problem with ocaml-lib) but instead try it and see if you like it.

```
let contents = 
   match z with
   Some c -> c;;
```

Variable `contents` is assigned `3`, but you get a warning:

> Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. Here is an example
>   of a value that is not matched: None

In the general case, you won't know that the expression you want to look inside is necessarily a `Some c`. The reason an option type was chosen is usually that sometimes that value can be `None`. Here the compiler is reminding you that you are not handling one of the possible cases.

You can pattern-match “in depth” and the compiler will still check for exhaustivity. Consider this function that takes an `(int option) option`:

```
let f x =
  match x with
  Some (Some c) -> c
  | None -> 0
  ;;
```

Here you forgot the case `Some (None)` and the compiler tells you so:

> Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. Here is an example
>   of a value that is not matched: Some None

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your first example is equivalent to `let Some c = z in c `

Comment: In this answer I am using exclusively `match with` for pattern-matching because the latter is the subject at hand and I do not think it hurts to associate it to a single construct at first.

Comment: I agree with you, which is why I added this factoid as a comment ;)

Answer (score 10):

The usual way to do this is with pattern matching.

```
# let x = Some 4;;
val x : int option = Some 4

# match x with
  | None -> Printf.printf "saw nothing at all\n"
  | Some v -> Printf.printf "saw %d\n" v;;
saw 4
- : unit = ()
```

You can write your own get function (though you have to decide
what you want to do when the value is None).

Comment: That is a good answer. To expand on that example, let's make x hold a string and print that:

https://gist.github.com/shehaaz/7165109

So potentially you can write a general function that handles a all types.

Answer (score 5):

You should listen to the above posters advice regarding type safety but also be aware that unsafe function such as Option.get (which is available in batteries btw) are usually suffixed with exn. If you're curious this is how Option.get or Option.get_exn could be implemented then:

```
let get_exn = function
  | Some x -> x
  | None   -> raise (Invalid_argument "Option.get")
```