# Red black trees with classes in OCaml

Tags: class, oop, ocaml, binary-tree, red-black-tree

Does anyone know how to implement red black trees with classes in OCaml?
At least the class properties and initializers? I'm new in OCaml.

What I tried:

```
type data  = {key: int; value: string}

class node (data: data) = 
   object (self)
   val mutable d = data
   val mutable color = 1
   val mutable left = ref (None: node option) 
   val mutable right = ref (None: node option) 
   val mutable parent = ref (None: node option) 

   method getLeft = left
   method getRight = right
   method getParent = parent
   method getColor = color
   method getData = d
   method setLeft (l: node option ref) = left := !l
   method setRight (l: node option ref) = right := !l
   method setParent (l: node option ref) = parent := !l
 end;;



class rbtree =
   object (self)
   val mutable root = ref (None: node option)
   val mutable nullNode = ref (None: node option)
   method searchNode (aNode: node option ref) (key: data) = begin
   if aNode = nullNode || key == (!aNode)#getData then aNode;
end;

end;;
```

I get the error `This expression has type node option
       It has no method getData`

What I am trying is to make something like this code that is written in C++:

```
 struct Node
 {
  int data;
  Node *parent;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
  int color;
 };

 typedef Node *NodePtr;
 class RedBlackTree
 {
    private:
       NodePtr root;
       NodePtr TNULL;
       void initializeNULLNode(NodePtr node, NodePtr parent)
       {
           node->data = 0;
           node->parent = parent;
           node->left = nullptr;
           node->right = nullptr;
           node->color = 0;
       }

  NodePtr searchTreeHelper(NodePtr node, int key)
  {
     if (node == TNULL || key == node->data)
     {
      return node;
     }
     if (key < node->data)
     {
       return searchTreeHelper(node->left, key);
     }
     return searchTreeHelper(node->right, key);
  }
};
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer this, because there's no clear reason to use a class to represent a tree type. Furthermore, you say "classes" as if you expect to have more than one class. It might help if you explain your requirements more carefully. However, this sounds like a homework assigment and you should be prepared to do almost all the work youself. In particular, you should ideally ask your questions after writing some code and having specific problems with it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, you are right. It is homework. I will update now my question with a code I tried.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield, could you please look once again now? Thank you.

Comment: Regarding the error `This expression has type node option. It has no method getData` it looks like this is because the value is of type `node options` but you're trying to access the field of a value of type `node`. So you need to first get the `node` out of the `option`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288752/1187277

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay, thank you @halfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error you're seeing, @Shon is correct. You have this expression:

```
if aNode = nullNode || key == (!aNode)#getData then aNode;
```

The type of `aNode` is `node option ref`. So that means the type of `!anode` is `node option`. An option value isn't an object (an instance of a class). So you can't call the method `getData` on it.

Again, as @Shon says, you need to retrieve the value of `!aNode` (if there is one). This will give you a node, which is an object and does have a `getData` method.

It would be messy to write this code in-line in your `if` test. So you might write a function like this:

```
let node_option_has_value node_opt value =
   match node_opt with
   | None -> false
   | Some node -> node#getData = value
```

As a side comment, you should not be using the physical equality operator (`==`) to do comparisons. This operator is for special cases, not for general use.

The equality comparison operator in OCaml is `=` (as in my example code).